# Google Area Chart: Need to show data in tooltip

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using google area chart. By default it shows information in tool tip at nodes. But I need to display data at any point of linear area on mouse hover.
Can anyone please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate additional points manually and provide it for a chart.

Answer (score 0):

The API only provides the capability to display tooltips for points specified in your DataTable.  If you want to be able to spawn tooltips at any point on a line, then you have to manually interpolate the values in between the data points.  It is not possible to interpolate *all* values in between two points (there are, after all, an infinite number of points on a line of any length), so you have to pick some increment and calculate the values for points along that increment.  Here's an example:

```
// manually interpolate values between adjacent data points
// set the unit increment for x values to interpolate
// smaller increment values will give more fine-grained resolution to the interpolated values
// larger incremenet values will give better performance in some browsers (particularly IE8)
var increment = 0.1, dx, dy, p1, p2;
for (var i = 1, cnt = data.getNumberOfRows(); i < cnt; i++) {
    p1 = {x: data.getValue(i - 1, 0), y: data.getValue(i - 1, 1)};
    p2 = {x: data.getValue(i, 0), y: data.getValue(i, 1)};
    dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    for (var j = increment; j < dx; j += increment) {
        data.addRow([p1.x + j, p1.y + j * dy / dx]);
    }
}
// sort the data so the chart will draw correctly
data.sort(0);
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/Q42nu/